# ANOVA using R - unsure of if analysis is appropriate, and if variables need to be numeric

Tags: r, anova

I'm doing an ANOVA to compare the results of two trials.

Individuals had to walk towards a bucket blindfolded, with their deviation from the target recorded. I want to see if individuals get better with practice (are trial-2 deviations lower than trial-1) and is there a relationship between the trials regarding gender and handedness (left handed/right handed).

**Is an ANOVA appropriate?**

Also, I'm having trouble in R because I've put gender as M and F, and Handedness as L or R. Do I need to make these numerical or not?

Comment: Analyses in R should be able to manage just fine with variables coded M/F and L/R; it has probably already made them factors (check by something like `is.factor(gender)` or even just use `str()` on them); if not, try `as.factor()`. You could analyze this data using ANOVA, yes

Comment: *Note, although this question mentions using R, I see no reason to think it is off-topic. The main question seems to be "is an ANOVA appropriate", which is clearly on-topic & has nothing to do with R.*

Comment: @gung I agree -- and have highlighted the main question to make it clear that an on-topic question is being asked.

Comment: Because each individual contributes two data, you may want to use repeated measures ANOVA here. If you are less familiar with that, you could try using difference scores.

Comment: @gung: Since it is about two trials, its probably not a paired design. This should be clarified by the OP.